# PowerShell filter by OU

Tags: powershell

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

Get-ADComputer -Filter {enabled -eq $true} -properties *|select Name,
   | Out-File -FilePath c:\Powershell.txt
```

I am trying to export a list to txt file and have it display a list of all the computers on my domain by name and the OU or group it is assigned to. i am able to retrieve the name with this, but would like to ad a OU Colum.

Comment: How many computer objects are there on your domain? `Get-ADComputer -Filter {enabled -eq $true}` will certainly time out if there are too many objects.

Comment: it runs and displays the hostname fine,i just wanted to add a Colum for OU

Answer (score 2):

Since the `DistinguishedName` value contains the OU RDN, we can extract it with a bit of string splitting magic:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * |Select Name,@{Name='OU';Expression={$_.DistinguishedName -split '(?<!\\),' |Select -Index 1}}
```

This will give us only the RDN (ie. `OU=Company Users`), if you want the full DN of the OU, do:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * |Select Name,@{Name='OU';Expression={$_.DistinguishedName -split '(?<!\\),',2 |Select -Skip 1}}
```

---

The pattern `(?<!\\),` will match any `,` in the DN only if *not* preceded by `\` - this is to avoid splitting on escaped `,`'s, like in `CN=LastName\, FirstName,OU=Users,...`

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, I would derive the OU from the `DistinguishedName` value. It will be quicker than running additional ActiveDirectory module PowerShell commands. You can then output the OU value using [Select-Object's calculated properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-7.1#example-10--create-calculated-properties-for-each-inputobject). I would also recommend outputting to CSV (using [Export-Csv](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv?view=powershell-7.1)) since that format is easily readable by PowerShell and other file editing tools.

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter 'Enabled -eq $true' |
    Select-Object Name,@{n='OU';e={$_.DistinguishedName -creplace '^.*?,(?=[A-Z]{2}=.*)'}} |
        Export-Csv -Path c:\Computers.csv
```

Note that the CSV export will have a header row and values will be delimited by comma. If you prefer a different delimiter, you can use the `-Delimiter` parameter or your PowerShell session's default list separator with the `-UseCulture` switch.

`-creplace` is a case-sensitive version of `-replace` operator.

`^.*?,(?=[A-Z]{2}=.*)` is regex syntax for matching the text to replace. `^` denotes the start of the string. `.*?,` matches a few characters as possible until a `,` is matched. But since a `CN` value can contain `,` characters, we only want to stop matching when it precedes `OU=` or `DC=`. This is why we have positive lookahead `(?=[A-Z]{2}=.*)`. `[A-Z]{2}` matches exactly two capital letters followed by `=`.

Comment: Agreed. Must be the most perfect timing ever.

Answer (score 0):

This what I do, it is a bit slower than the other examples provided but it will prevent any timeout on the `Get-ADcomputer` cmdlet. I'm also using `CanonicalName` to have an absolute path of the OU because OUs can have the same name and Canonical is easier to read than Distinguished.

```
$OUs = Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter * -Properties CanonicalName

$Result = foreach($OU in $OUs)
{
    $hash = @{
        Filter = 'Enabled -eq $true'
        SearchScope = 'OneLevel'
        SearchBase = $OU.DistinguishedName
    }
    
    foreach($computer in Get-ADComputer @hash)
    {
        [pscustomobject]@{
            ComputerName = $computer.Name
            OU = $OU.CanonicalName
        }
    }
}
```