# Getting computername and the Canonical and distinguished OU name from AD

Tags: powershell

I have a list of servers where I need to get the OU, I have put together a script that will do this.

```
Get-ADOrganizationalUnit 
    -Identity $(($adComputer = Get-ADComputer -Identity $env:COMPUTERNAME).DistinguishedName.SubString($adComputer.DistinguishedName.IndexOf("OU=")))
```

The issue here is that the OU name is hard to read and not easy on the eye, so I figured out that what i need is the CanonicalName. However here is the problem.

I have come up with the snippet below.

```
Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter * -properties CanonicalName, DistinguishedName 
    | select-Object CanonicalName,DistinguishedName
```

The problem with the above is that it gets everything in AD, I need to be able to filter by servername so that when I load up the server list in a file, I can use a foreach loop to get a report of the servername and the OU, I have tried to use the -Server filter to no avail, as I believe that is for the AD server.

During my research I found, [PowerShell filter by OU](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66568822/powershell-filter-by-ou/66569629#66569629). In my test environment, it has been running for hours with no results back.

The snippet below will return groups, I cannot get servername filter to work.

```
Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Properties CanonicalName -Filter * 
    | Sort-Object CanonicalName 
    | ForEach-Object { [pscustomobject]@ {
        Name          = Split-Path $_.CanonicalName -Leaf
        CanonicalName = $_.CanonicalName
        UserCount     = @(Get-AdUser -Filter * -SearchBase $_.DistinguishedName -SearchScope OneLevel).Count
      }
     }
```

Comment: Oof I didn't write that linked answer :S The computer list is it from a Csv or a text file? Could you add that line to your code and if it's a Csv, please add the column name

Comment: The pipes have to be on the same line as the previous command, the next command can be on a new line.

Comment: @AbrahamZinala This rule does not apply anymore for PowerShell v7 and up. ;-) You can actually put the pipe symbol on a new line.

Comment: @olaf, good to know. I'm still stuck on 5.1 for my work work environment so haven't delve I to Pwsh core yet. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would do it:

1. First query all the computers from your list. Here I'm assuming the computer list is coming from a CSV and the computers are on a column named **Computers**.
2. Get the computer's Organizational Unit by removing the Common Name from their *DistinguishedName*: `(.... -split '(?=OU=)',2)[-1]`
3. Add the computers objects to a [*Hash Table*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_hash_tables?view=powershell-7.2) where the Keys are the computer's OUs. This will let us query each OU only once.
4. Loop over the *Hash Table* keys (**OU's DistinguishedName**) querying their *CanonicalName*.
5. Create a new object for each computer with the desired properties.
6. Export the result to a Csv.

```
# If it's a txt file instead:
# $computers = Get-Content path/to/computers.txt
$csv = Import-Csv path/to/csv.csv
$map = @{}

# If it's a txt file, instead:
# foreach($computer in $computers)
foreach($computer in $csv.Computers)
{
    try
    {
        $adComputer = Get-ADComputer $computer
        $ou = ($adComputer.DistinguishedName -split '(?=OU=)',2)[-1]
        if($val = $map[$ou]) {
            $map[$ou] = $val + $adComputer
            continue
        }
        $map[$ou] = , $adComputer
    }
    catch
    {
        Write-Warning $_.Exception.Message
    }
}

$result = foreach($ou in $map.Keys)
{
    $params = @{
        Identity = $ou
        Properties = 'canonicalName'
    }

    try
    {
        $canonical = Get-ADOrganizationalUnit @params
        foreach($computer in $map[$ou])
        {
            [pscustomobject]@{
                'Computer Name'        = $computer.Name
                'OU DistinguishedName' = $ou
                'OU CanonicalName'     = $canonical.CanonicalName
            }
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        Write-Warning $_.Exception.Message
    }
}

$result | Export-Csv .... -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: I am very grateful thanks. If I decided not to use a csv, i believe I can use `Get-content 'path'` and remove the computers column header which comes with import-csv in the code ?

Comment: @learner my pleasure, happy to help. I have added 2 comments at the top of the code considering the data is coming from a text file.

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work? Filter on a computer name or a wildcard pattern, then get the OU name and OU canonical name using the computer's `DistinguishedName` and `CanonicalName` properties:

```
$filter = "Name -eq 'SERVER01'" # exact name
# OR
$filter = "Name -like 'SERVER*'" # anything that starts with SERVER

Get-ADComputer -Filter $filter -Properties canonicalname |
    select name,
    @{ name = 'OU' ; expression = { [void]($_.DistinguishedName -match 'OU=.+$'); $Matches[0] } },
    @{ name = 'OU Canonical' ; expression = { $_.CanonicalName -replace "/$($_.Name)" } }
```